# Javascript window.open changes the main page too

Tags: javascript, html, facebook

I'm having trouble opening a popup to share on facebook.
When I press the "button" popup opens correctly, but back in the page from where I called it also shows the contents of that url.
I tried leaving blank href, also with #, but none get a good result.

This is the code:

```
<a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?s=100&amp;p[url]=http://www.misbooks.com.ar/titulo.php?id=3304&amp;p[title]=Juego de tronos&amp;p[summary]=Tras el largo verano, el invierno se acerca a los Siete Reinos. Lord Eddars Stark, señor de Invernalia, deja sus dominios para unirse a la corte del rey Robert Baratheon el Usurpador, hombre díscolo y otrora guerrero audaz cuyas mayores aficiones son comer, beber y engendrar bastardos. Eddard...&amp;p[images][0]=http://www.misbooks.com.ar/img/portadas/3304.jpg" onclick="window.open(this.href, 'targetWindow','toolbar=no,location=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,width=626,height=436')">
                                    <i class="pluginButtonIcon img sp_like sx_like_fav alignButtonImage"></i>
                                    <span class="accessible_elem alignButtonImage">Compartir</span>
                                </a>
```

Someone can help me?

Thanks.

Comment: Get the click event on <a> tag and prevent default it in event handler, the do rest of the work you want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add return false; to your onclick function:

```
onclick="window.open(this.getAttribute('_url'), 'targetWindow','toolbar=no,location=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,width=626,height=436'); return false;"
```

Comment: Thanks, it was exactly what I was missing

Comment: What was missing was put return false in the onclick, and the answer you gave me did not mention it, anyway thanks for answering

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can try this:

```
<a href="" _url="http://stackoverflow.com" onclick="window.open(this.getAttribute('_url'), 'targetWindow','toolbar=no,location=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,width=626,height=436')">
     <i class="pluginButtonIcon img sp_like sx_like_fav alignButtonImage"></i>
     <span class="accessible_elem alignButtonImage">Compartir</span>
</a>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I had tried that and it did not work. I just needed to put a return false in the onclick

Comment: fine.. I wouldn't answer if it did not work. @Rodrigo